# angular 4 - include 3rd plugin in a component

Tags: angular

I want to include a 3rd party plugin into a component, specifically the CKEDITOR, but it can be any plugin, even a jQuery plugin.

I know there exists ng-ckeditor package but I do not want to use that, because what if tomorrow I want to use an arbitrary jquery plugin, I don't want to have to have an angular only alternative.

So normally this is how the CKEDITOR is called:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content'); // The form has and id of content
```

I have downloaded the ckeditor via npm and included it in angular-cli.json, but how do I actually call it inside of the component, as simply calling `CKEDITOR` of course does not work?

Comment: did you try to declare it before using? declare CKEDITOR: any;

Comment: @FetraR. No, didn't know about that functionality. it works! Post this as answer please, it helps newbies to angular and helps with other libs as well.

Comment: should be declare var CKEDITOR: any; actually but yea that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is already loaded:

- npm install ckeditor
- add it in angular-cli.json (scripts)

You just need to declare it before using it:

```
 declare CKEDITOR: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add other editor than use the below url:-

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/